# I can't get an output in my python code in Zapier

Tags: python, zapier

I've been reading Zapier documentation using python and they show this example:

```
output= {'has_lunch': False}

if input.get('body') and 'lunch' in input['body']:
        output['has_lunch'] = True
```

Actually this looks like something that I am looking for, the main difference between the example and my code is that I would like to pass more than one parameters  and evaluate those paratemeters to obtein an specific output.

For example:

```
output= {'Mango': 1, 'Apple': 2}

if input.get('Fruits') and 'Mango' in input['Fruits']:
        output['Mango'] =  1
elif input.get('Fruits') and 'Apple' in input['Fruits']:
        output['Apple'] =  2
```

Error: output missing Please define output or return early.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
if input.get('Fruits') and 'Mango' in input['Fruits']:
        mango = 1
else: mango = None

if input.get('Fruits') and 'Apple' in input['Fruits']:
        apple = 2
else: apple = None       
output = {'mango': mango, 'apple': apple}
```

It says `Error: output missing Please define output or return early` due to how zapier is setup. In JS you can either do `output` or do an if/else and do a `return`. I'm no expert in Python, but you would need to use the equivalent of `return` in JS for your code to work, otherwise it will stop the function upon reaching the first `output`.